# How to save ListView content

Tags: java, android, listview

i have listview with text and picture, and i want if the user selected settings: "Do not update" does not update the ListView at the start, but load saved.

Is it possible to save the ListView?

Comment: Sure it's possible, though you probably rather want to save the DATA the listView is showing...

Comment: You can give me link about this?

Comment: Check out these android developer pages : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html , http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html. The easiest way is to save/load it to/from SharedPreferences. If you have lots of data, a SQL Database is better.